# Imagick from parallel PHP scripts

Tags: php, imagick

I need to run one Imagick instance from few parallel php scripts handling different images.

I succeeded running one instance from one PHP script using Apache 2.4.51 (Win64), PHP 7.4.25, Imagick 3.5.1-7.4-ts.

But I failed running two instances in parallel. The first runs fine, but the second PHP script is unwillingly suspended waiting until the end of the first PHP script. When released the second script runs fine too.

Basic PHP script 1 code:

```
0. (some independant code)
1. $Image = new Imagick($Path1);
2. $Resolution = $Image->getimageresolution();
3. $Image->clear();
```

Basic PHP script 2 code (suspended on line 1):

```
0. (some independant code)
1. $Image = new Imagick($Path2);
2. $Resolution = $Image->getimageresolution();
3. $Image->clear();
```

I tried using several Imagick options (ie: RESOURCETYPE_THREAD) or functions (ie: destroy) without further success. I would need a solution to fully release Imagick after its usage, or to allow parallel calls.

Comment: My guess is that you are using file based PHP sessions and your script keeps session open during its complete runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Álvaro. Indeed, but why Imagick is not "released" after its usage allowing an other Imagick instance to be run by PHP script 2 just after or ideally in parallel (and so before the end of the PHP script 1) ?

Comment: Because Imagick is not holding or awaiting anything. If the session file is locked by other process, the first call to `session_start()` (or implicit session loading) will wait until the file is released.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry I am not sure to understand what is exactly blocking what. We have 2 PHP scripts each with its session, and its Imagick instance. What should I do to avoid this lock please?

Comment: It would help if you included a [mcve] (i.e. also how you serve this and how you trigger it). Also, provide the actual observations and not just the interpretation ("failed running two instances in parallel").

Comment: I don't have access to your computer or source code, I can't tell for sure what's blocking your script. I've provided a guess but only you can confirm if that's the reason.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich and Álvaro for your answers. I unfortunately did not find a simple way to provide a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Rather by trying to parallelize the usage of the Imagick php class, I workarounded the issue by parallelizing the usage of the Imagick command.

Basic PHP script 1 code:

```
0. (some independant code)
1. exec("magick identify -format ...".$Path1, $Output, $Return);
2. $Resolution = $Output[0];
```

Basic PHP script 2 code (no longer suspended to script 1):

```
0. (some independant code)
1. exec("magick identify -format ...".$Path2, $Output, $Return);
2. $Resolution = $Output[0];
```